# How to resize custom UISegmentedControl inside navigation bar for iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I am new in iPhone app development. I am using customized uisegmentedcontrol inside navigation bar.

This code works well for iPhone.

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES]; 
    profileSegmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"seg1", @"seg2", @"seg3", @"seg4", nil]];


[profileSegmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(seg1Button) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

**profileSegmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(40, 25, 310, 30);**
profileSegmentControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
profileSegmentControl.momentary = YES;

//[profileSegmentControl sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *profileSegmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:profileSegmentControl];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = profileSegmentBarItem;
```

Now, when I change the orientation from portrait to landscape, how to change the uisegmentedcontroll buttons' co-ordinates in CGRectMake? When in landscape, the width should be 510 instead of 310.

Cannot use [segmentControlObject sizeToFit] as i have hidden the "back" navigation button of navigation bar. I tried this, but the width of segmentedControl does not cover the entire navigation bar.

I am aware of  (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation method, but you cannot call this under viewDidLoad or under any method.

Using xcode 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Do like this
if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ){
      FACING = @"PU";
  }
  if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ){
      FACING = @"PD";
  }
  if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ){
      FACING = @"LL";
  }
  if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ){
      FACING = @"LR";
  }
```

So set the frame whatever you want in the respective blocks.it works.

Comment: user2582825 : I really appreciate your help, its working fine in iphone now.. now i want to implement same thing in iPad which should be in one .ipa file only.. please guide

Comment: In that case you will have to check like this                       if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

}else{                                                              } And put all the above four if conditions you have used in iphone code in each if and else block.It will do for iPad also..